# \endcsname errors in classicthesis

Tags: classicthesis

I have been using classicthesis ( http://www.miede.de/index.php?page=classicthesis ) for about a year now with no issues with TeXnicCenter.

I last compiled my document successfully yesterday. Today I updated my MikTex 2.9 packages under Win7 using the Maintenance(Admin) application - I did not pay attention to which packages were updated. I Refreshed FNDB and Updated Formats.

My next compile resulted in 132 errors such as the following:

```
l.18 \setcounter{paragraph}{0}

The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.

! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
               \endcsname 
l.18 \setcounter{paragraph}{0}

The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
 <to be read again> 
               \endcsname 
l.18 \setcounter{paragraph}{0}

A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
               \endcsname 
l.19 \setcounter{subparagraph}{0}
```

So I re-downloaded `classicthesis` and compiled it. The result was 101 errors of a similar nature. even with this minimal `classicthesis.tex` file I get 101 errors. This along with `classicthesis-config.tex` should hopefully perform the duties of a MWE.

```
% Copyright (C) 2012 Andr\'e Miede http://www.miede.de

\documentclass[ twoside,openright,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,headinclude,%1headlines,%     letterpaper a4paper
            footinclude=true,cleardoublepage=empty,abstractoff, % <--- obsolete, remove (todo)
            BCOR=5mm,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt,%11pt,a4paper,%
            ngerman,american,%
            ]{scrreprt}

\input{classicthesis-config}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

I have used the classicthesis-config.tex example file and my modified file with the same result. Relevent files are available at: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/classicthesis/

```
%http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/classicthesis/classicthesis-config.tex
%http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/classicthesis/classicthesis.sty
```

I have tried deleting all the `.aux` files. 
In my dissertation, removing `\usepackage[polutonikogreek,english]{babel}`  results in some 50 errors fewer, but this does not occur in the attached example.

Given that I have relied on `\usepackage[polutonikogreek,english]{babel}` for extensive ancient Greek text, I really need to use this.

Any ideas as to the cause and/or the remedy for my woes? Thank you for your time thus far.

Comment: At first, I thought, the `-` character in `\input{classicthesis-config}` could be the source of the problem, but after tests, your example runs without errors, if I use the latest version of TeXLive and also of `classigthesis-config`. I can however say nothing about the changes you made. Please provide your version of that file also.

Comment: Why don't you use `\usepackage{classicthesis}`?

Comment: Thank you Christian. The examples I provided are the example files created by the author of the classicthesis package. Compiling his example files resulted in the same errors as compiling my files, thus I thought supplying his files would ease this process. Solving the problem of compiling the examples should solve the problem of compiling my files. However, as they compile without error for you, I suspect there is now some issue on my installation of MikTex.

Comment: Herbert, the example I supplied is the example provided by the classicthesis author. Up until today, the example he provided worked perfectly for me, so I didn't change it.

Comment: You will usually get errors if you try to compile a document with no content, won't you? (That is, nothing between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`.)

Comment: @cfr: Normally there is just a warning `No pages of output` when there is nothing between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` Do you have a specific example when there is an error (apart from from a faulty `\AtBeginDocument` which might in turn then produce such an error?

Comment: @Evyn: Yes, I also tested the files with `\usepackage[polutonikogreek,english]{babel}` and I got no errors, so I assume, that your MikTeX installation has gotten corrupted.

Comment: The errors occur with or without content. The same errors occur regardless of content - I can put some random text in and the result is the same as with no text. The number of errors increase by 1 per number of pages. As Christian states, the problem is likely localised to my installation. Thank you all for your time.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks. I'm probably just confusing what my editor considers an error with what TeX considers one.

Comment: @Evyn: It seems, that MikTeX has severe problems since about two weeks, regarding the increased questions about problems after updating MikTeX, at least I have this impression. I do not use MikTeX, my environment is TeXLive on Linux, so I am not able to provide any help about MikTeX issues unfortunately :-(

Comment: @cfr: That is a clever editor, preventing you to make empty documents ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I suspect what upsets it is the lack of an output file (pdf or dvi or whatever). Sadly, it is not quite so clever at telling you *what* it finds so distressing!

Comment: Commenting out \pagenumbering{roman} has removed all the errors at compile time. So I move closer to an answer and solution.

Comment: and \RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag} also had to be removed.

Comment: VtC as unclear. The problem seems to be (to have been) some glitch in MikTeX at the time. The information about what errors occur with which document (and which magical `classicthesis-config`) are unclear to me. If the problem persists, you can update and improve the question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because *see comment above*